# ¿Me puedo subscribir a una pregunta de otra persona y recibir notificaciones?

Tags: soporte, preguntas, notificaciones

¿Puedo subscribirme a una pregunta donde no he participado (ni preguntando, ni respondiendo ni comentando)? De tal manera que reciba notificaciones como recibe el OP en su bandeja en caso de que haya alguna novedad.

Como usuario normal no veo forma de hacerlo y no sé si es algún tipo de privilegio que se obtiene con reputación.

Comment: creo que esa funcionalidad no existe, lo que existe es marcar tu pregunta como favorita, y luego puedes verla desde tu perfil

Comment: Tal y como dice @Jack, no es posible. Además de marcarla como favorita, también puedes usar el RSS propio de la pregunta que aparece en la parte inferior, en _Fuente de la pregunta_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No es posible *suplantar* al autor de la pregunta recibir notificaciones de Stack Overflow cuando hay nuevas respuestas. Tampoco es algo que cambie con la reputación: todos los usuarios tienen las mismas herramientas en este caso.

Eso sí, tienes distintas alternativas:

- Guarda la pregunta en favoritos apretando en la estrellita que aparece debajo de los botones de votar. Así, entrando en tu perfil, verás que la sección [*Favoritas*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/142239/ordago?tab=favorites) se ilumina cada vez que haya algún cambio (ediciones, respuestas, comentarios y alguna cosa más).
- Usa la fuente de la pregunta suscribiéndote al RSS. Debajo de cada bloque de pregunta-respuestas hay un texto *Fuente de la pregunta* que lleva a un RSS. Guárdalo y consúltalo con tu cliente de RSS favorito.
- Utiliza IFTTT con una receta como por ejemplo https://ifttt.com/applets/4447 para conectar el RSS con tu email.

Fuente y otras posibles soluciones sacado de Meta.SE en [Subscribe to a particular question by email (not RSS)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113630/209901).